# Iterate through list of tables and remove tables that contains a String

Tags: r

I have multiple tables that I have scraped from a docx document.

```
library(docxtractr)

# Import docx
report = docxtractr::read_docx("/Users/nicholas/Desktop/LNW.docx")

# get all the tables
tbls <- docx_extract_all_tbls(report)

# get tables into seperate variables
tbl1 = tbls[[1]]
tbl2 = tbls[[2]]
tbl3 = tbls[[3]]
tbl4 = tbls[[4]]
tbl5 = tbls[[5]]
tbl6 = tbls[[6]]
tbl7 = tbls[[7]]
tbl8 = tbls[[8]]

myList = list(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5, tbl6, tbl7, tbl8)
```

I will be iterating through thousands of documents, but there will be a maximum of 8 tables in each report.

Not all the tables are relevant though, and if they don't contain the text `'inspection date'`, I want to remove them completely.

So far, I know how to iterate through the tables in the list, but the string check isn't working, and it won't remove any tables from the list even if try it outside of the for/if block (I get an `Error in myList[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'`)

```
for (i in myList) {
  if(any("inspection date" %in% i )){
    myList = within(myList, rm(myList[i]))
  }
}
```

I think it could be as the list of dataframes is a list of lists? but it does say tibble.

[image]

I don't have a reproducible example as its sensitive information, but any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: What’s the purpose of the intermediate separate variables?! Just do `myList = tbls` — or just use `tbls` directly. (As a general rule, it never makes sense to assign list members to consecutively-numbered, separate variables.)

Comment: Thank you, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Filter` :

```
result <- Filter(function(x) any(x == 'inspection date', na.rm = TRUE), myList)
```

Some variations of the above would be :

```
myList[sapply(myList, function(x) any(x == 'inspection date', na.rm = TRUE))]
purrr::keep(myList, ~any(.x == 'inspection date', na.rm = TRUE))
```